# Observable value from one page to other

Tags: c#, knockout.js

Not able to access observable of parent to child page. Scenario listed below...

1. I have a page listing all the user information (say home page) in a grid and it has action button as well
2. on click of the action button, i will loading another page (may be user detail page) with the user basic information from the prev (home) page

The code base is something like this

1. `HomePage.cshtml` has `homepagevm.js`
2. on click of action button, I have function in `homepagevm.js` and setting the select user info into a observables.  I tried with alert statement and I got the values desired
3. The `DetailPage.cshtml` has the same `homepagevm.js` reference.  However I am not getting the value (`HomePagevm.UserName()`).

### code base:

In the homepage.cshtml

```
<a role="button" data-bind="click: $root.isUserdtl">User Detail</a><br>
@Scripts.Render("homepagevm.js")
```

`homepagevm.js` has `isUserDtl` method

```
homepagevm.isUserdtl= function (element) {
    homepagevm.UserName(element.UserName);
}
```

In the `Detailpage.cshtml`

```
<span data-bind="text: homepagevm.UserName()"></span>
@Scripts.Render("homepagevm.js")
```

I tried accessing by `<span data-bind="text: $root.UserName()"></span>` and without root syntax also.

I have problem using another VM for the detail page hence clubbed all my method calls in one single js file. Any help would be much appreciated. thank you.

Comment: If you go to the Detailspage, you need to tell the action method which user has been selected via a parameter on the action. Knockout observables won't persist between different pages, you will have to reload a new model on the second page. Regarding the child page, is it a popup or a redirected page, it's not clear from your question.

Comment: Thank you, Tanner.  It's a redirected page from js (window.location.href="page").

Comment: window.location.href does a complete page load of the new target HTML, CSS, JS everything so the data will not persist between these two pages. You have a couple of options post back the required data to the server and reload on the new page or pass what is needed on the query string between the pages

Comment: Thank you, Scott.  I managed it with querystring now.